# How to transpose one column in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to transpose only the status and count column

From

```
Week    Status   Count
2021-01  High    186
2021-01 Medium   21
2021-01 Low      632
2021-02 High     144
2021-02 Medium    2
2021-02 Low      20
2021-02 Very_High 648
```

to

```
 Week   High Medium Low Very_High
 2021-01 186  21    632    0
 2021-02 144  2     20   648
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pivot`:

```
out = df.pivot('Week', 'Status', 'Count').reset_index().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print(out)

# Output
      Week   High    Low  Medium  Very_High
0  2021-01  186.0  632.0    21.0        NaN
1  2021-02  144.0   20.0     2.0      648.0
```